# how to index dynamic routes in google using nextJS

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, seo

I know how to use reactJS, but now I am creating a web page made with nextJS to improve SEO, but I have a question.

How do I make my dynamic routes made with NextJS known to google? I understand that we have getStaticPaths and in routes we can put all the routes and by setting fallback to true we can add the dynamic routes without specifying them, but how do I do when I have a million routes and I want google to index them and they can appear in the searches? Thank you very much I hope someone helps me: D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide a sitemap, that search engines use to define what paths your site contains. That way they know which paths to crawl through.

Googling sitemap + next.js gave this tutorial for example, but for super simple site you could just define it manually too: https://cheatcode.co/tutorials/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-sitemap-with-next-js

Comment: In the sitemap can I add a million routes? I know it is somewhat exaggerated but I would like to know how medium.com does, for example, that all articles can be found from the google search engine.

For example my domian is:
Mydomain.com/article/[dynamicArticleId]

Comment: Google says that first 50k are ok, after that you need multiple sitemaps: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for solving my question

Comment: sitemap is still used nowadays, but for google there is an indexing api that you could use and submit as much url as you want as long as you have a bigger quota, it is much faster than waiting for google to schedule the next crawl  for your sitemap, in case you would like to build a dynamic sitemap in nextjs you can check  : https://learnjsx.com/category/4/posts/nextjs-sitemap